# Returning value from a method

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public class Request
{
    static string username = "ha@gmail.com";

    public string Send()
    {
        ///some variables           

        try
        {
            ///
        }

        catch (WebException e)
        {
            using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
            { 
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                using (Stream Data = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    string text = new StreamReader(Data).ReadToEnd();                
                }
            }
        }
        return text;
    }

}
```

Getting an error: 'text' does' t exist in the current context.  How to return the 'Text' value from the method.

Comment: because it is declare in the `catch` block scope not in the method scope..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public string Send()
{
    //define the variable outside of try catch
    string text = null; //Define at method scope
    ///some variables           
    try
    {
        ///
    }

    catch (WebException e)
    {
        using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
        {
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
            Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
            using (Stream Data = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                text = new StreamReader(Data).ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: I agree with you guys. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
public string Send()
{
    try {
        return "Your string value";
    }

    catch (WebException e) {
        using (WebResponse response = e.Response) { 
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
            Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
            using (Stream Data = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
               return new StreamReader(Data).ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize variable before `try clause` to use it outside of `try`:

```
public string Send()
{
    string text = null;

    try 
    {

    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
        {
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
            Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
            using (Stream Data = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                text = new StreamReader(Data).ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `text` as a local variable in `Send()`, not inside a sublocal block like here inside `using(...)`. Such it would be only valid there.